# Undefined variable - POST from a while input

Tags: php

i want to make a form with inputs. I have a while for inputs texts.

```
            <form class="form-horizontal new-lg-form" id="loginform" method="post">
        <?php $i = '1'; while($i <= '10') { $ids = 'factionQ'.$i.'';$intr = $row[$ids]; $i++;?>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Intrebarea #<?=$i?> =></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" id="app".$i."" name="app".$i."" placeholder="<?=$intr?>" required>
          </div>
       <?php } ?>
       <center><button class="btn btn-success" name="btn-apply" type="submit"> Aplica!</button></center> </form>
```

And this is the code for POST

```
      if(isset($_POST['btn-apply'])) {
    $i = '1'; while($i <= '10') { 
      $appos = filtrare($_POST['app'.$i.'']);
      echo $appos;
      $i++;
    }
  }
```

Error is:

```
Notice: Undefined index: app1 in D:\xampp\htdocs\panelrog\fapply.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: app2 in D:\xampp\htdocs\panelrog\fapply.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: app3 in D:\xampp\htdocs\panelrog\fapply.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: app4 in D:\xampp\htdocs\panelrog\fapply.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: app5 in D:\xampp\htdocs\panelrog\fapply.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: app6 in D:\xampp\htdocs\panelrog\fapply.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: app7 in D:\xampp\htdocs\panelrog\fapply.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: app8 in D:\xampp\htdocs\panelrog\fapply.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: app9 in D:\xampp\htdocs\panelrog\fapply.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: app10 in D:\xampp\htdocs\panelrog\fapply.php on line 13
```

Comment: Look at the resulting HTML output for your form. Your inputs are *not* named `app1`, `app2` etc…

Comment: It's automated name with while, app$i. $i is 1,2,3 etc

Comment: Yeah, *look at the resulting HTML* (right click View source, or Inspect element). Your inputs are just named `"app"`.

Comment: Not. It's name="app".$i.""

Comment: It's supposed to be `app1` though, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" id="app<?=$i?>" name="app<?=$i?>" placeholder="<?=$intr?>" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here whatever you trying yo make id and name are not proper

One more thing each tag should have only one id attribute so remove one in below... i have removed id="app"

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" id="app".$i."" name="app".$i."" placeholder="<?=$intr?>" required>
```

to

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput"  name="app<?=$i?>" placeholder="<?=$intr?>" required>
```